# Replace tasks with enumerate

Tags: macros, environments, enumerate, tasks

I'm trying to reformat a separate tex file without having to change the source file. What I want to do here is convert a tasks environment to a simpler enumerate environment. It *should* be simple -- replace "tasks" with "enumerate" and replace "\task" with "\item."

I've tried many variations on the MWE theme below, but to no avail. I'm sure it's some really simple syntax that I'm just not getting. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\task}{\item}
\newenvironment{tasks}[2]{\begin{enumerate} #2}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $\pi$
    \task $e^{\pi}$
    \task etc
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the layout of [`tasks`](//ctan.org/pkg/tasks), but just use an `enumerate` environment? That is, skip `(3)` supplied to the `tasks` environment? Also, [`tcolorbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) seems unnecessary in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\task}{\item}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tasks}{od()}{\enumerate}{\endenumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
  \task $\pi$
  \task $e^{\pi}$
  \task etc
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not (or only with some tricks) possible to define an optional argument with parentheses with `\newenvironment`. But it is rather easy with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. The details of said command are explained in the `xparse` manual: https://ctan.org/pkg/l3packages It is part of an up to date LaTeX kernel, though.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!